# How can I increase ExoPlayer's buffering time?

Tags: android, exoplayer

I'm using ExoPlayer to play videos/live streams on Android. If there is a problem with the connection (connection loss/reduced speed/etc.), the player goes into the buffering state - `STATE_BUFFERING`, trying to load data. After a couple of seconds it goes to `STATE_IDLE`. And if the connection is back and the player is in `STATE_IDLE`, it will not start playing. If the connection is restored and the player is in `STATE_BUFFERING`, it will load the data and start playing.
How to change the buffering timeout? To make it as big as possible, to make ExoPlayer wait for data as long as possible.

ExoPlayer initialization:

```kotlin
exoPlayer = ExoPlayer.Builder(context)
            .build()
```

Data source initialization:

```kotlin
val dataSourceFactory = DefaultHttpDataSource.Factory()
val mediaSource = HlsMediaSource.Factory(dataSourceFactory)
        .createMediaSource(link)

exoPlayer?.setMediaSource(mediaSource)
exoPlayer?.playWhenReady = false
exoPlayer?.prepare()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to customize `LoadErrorHandlingPolicy` to change the number of retries and the delay between each try. Exoplayer uses `DefaultLoadErrorHandlingPolicy` as a default implementation which retries for 3 times and after that propagates the error.

[This link](https://medium.com/google-exoplayer/load-error-handling-in-exoplayer-488ab6908137) can be handy for customizing `DefaultLoadErrorHandlingPolicy` to better fit your needs.

Answer (score 0):

The `LoadControl` interface defines the buffering strategy of ExoPlayer. 
ExoPlayer comes with a default implementation - `DefaultLoadControl`. 
You can configure the `DefaultLoadControl` using a `DefaultLoadControl.Builder` with necessary parameters, like bufferForPlaybackMs, minBufferMs/maxBufferMs.

Comment: Which setting exactly should I use to increase the buffering time? None of the listed parameters helped. I have the same buffering time - ~40s.